# Turning a computer on remotely, but still on the same network

Tags: networking, server, ssh, suspend

I have a home server running Ubuntu 14.04 and a huge first world problem.

I like to conserve power so I leave the server off most times when I'm not using it. But when I have to turn it on I have to walk up to the 3rd floor of my house to do so.

I use an OSX laptop to ssh into my home box - is there any way to remotely turn the server on if it's on my home network? I know Windows system and WOL - wake on lan - but I didn't know if that was (a) applicable in the linux world or (b) just intended to wake up from a sleep, not physically turn the machine on.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it actual server hardware?  You may have IPMI, if so, you can control the power using it.

Comment: Wake-on-LAN is platform-independent; any application that sends "magic packets" can wake up computers from shutdown state (as long mains power is not off) regardless of the OS it boots into afterwards.  I read this from [here](http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Set_up_Wake-on-LAN_for_Ubuntu) which tells you how to set it up. So it seems that it would wake even if you set your server to hibernate just as long as its not physically shut off you should be able to wake on LAN . ... as long as your network card is capable/

Comment: Thanks both of you! I have an HP Proliant Microserver. I'm pretty new at this, so I'm trying to figure out what the motherboard is and whether it will support Wake-on-LAN or IPMI. I dumped my system specs into a gist here - https://gist.github.com/fearthechop/0559c359f26b5530bf001196e3f92044

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is "wakeonlan".

Most modern motherboards support it.  I actually haven't come across one that doesn't yet if it is for a x86 processor.

Ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo apt-get install wakeonlan
```

Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt install wakeonlan
```

To wake your pc up, find the MAC address of your NIC and issue the command.

```
wakeonlan <MAC_ADDRESS>
```

That easy!

Comment: Thanks! Marking this as accepted since I was able to get it working with these steps earlier. Just also wanted to point out that I used John Orion's solution in the comments above initially, so it's worth checking that out as well. Just can't accept a comment as accepted :)